# Troubleshooting RCP Eclipse product build

Tags: maven, plugins, rcp, tycho, target-platform

I have a custom Eclipse build branded with my company logos and optimized for my work.

The custom Eclipse builds correctly with Tycho but I want to add the Maven integration, so I added m2e.wtp to the required plugin dependencies and the m2e repository to my target platform. The mvn clean install goes well. However, when I build and launch Eclipse, it no long has any of my customizations, perspectives, splash settings, or icons.

**How do I determine where the error is? How do I debug this problem?**

I tried to add the m2e repository and add the m2e to the product instead, but it doesn't work.

I thought that adding m2e.wtp to the required plugins dependencies and the repository to the target platform would be enough, but it doens't work.

Comment: `org.eclipse.m2e.feature` is the main m2e feature, you probably need to include that.

Comment: I already added m2e.feature, but when i execute mvn install and the executable created, it doesnt have my customization.

Comment: What customizations are missing exactly? Could you please show what you have installed where and is missing even so.